# JQuery Mobile listview links not loading properly after back button press

Tags: listview, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.1.0 to build a simple mobile website that incorporates a listview. I've got an issue with the nested links and back button presses. On Chrome (Linux) the URL goes back to `domain.com/#&ui-page=0-2` but displays only the twirling loader and a blank page, and on Android the listview re-appears, but clicking on a new link initiates odd behaviour; the twirly loader twirls, a page loads, and then the browser returns to the listview by itself. This is obviously undesirable. I've set `data-ajax="false" data-transition="none"` because the links are created by a foreach() PHP script and require the `page_id` value to be sent via GET.

I've also disabled data transitions in the `page` and `listview` containers, and then put the following in the `<head>` tags:

```
<script language=javascript>
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
  });
</script>
```

I'm at a bit of a loss to know what's going wrong, and can't find mention of an similar issue. The transitions are not at all needed, nor the caching behaviour, as I'm attempting to use JQM simply for its widget goodness. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Quick Fix:**

```
<script language=javascript>
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
  });
</script>
```